# ubuntu 14.04 package install fail (apt-get install error)

Tags: 14.04, apt

I was trying to install some packages from a repository with this command:

```
controller@controller:~$  sudo apt-get install nova-api nova-cert  nova-conductor nova-consoleauth nova-novncproxy nova-scheduler python-novaclient
```

During the middle of installation, when it start to unpack them, like this:

```
Selecting previously unselected package nova-common.
Preparing to unpack .../nova-common_1%3a2014.1.3-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nova-common (1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2) ...
```

I restarted the system by accident.

Now it seems some of the packages are broken, because it gives me these errors when I try to install with the `apt-get` install command again:

```
controller@controller:~$  sudo apt-get install nova-api nova-cert  nova-conductor nova-consoleauth nova-novncproxy nova-scheduler python-novaclient
[sudo] password for controller: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  nova-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nova-api nova-cert nova-common nova-conductor nova-consoleauth
  nova-novncproxy nova-scheduler python-novaclient
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/177 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,112 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package python-novaclient.
(Reading database ... 211230 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-novaclient_1%3a2.17.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-novaclient (1:2.17.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nova-common.
Preparing to unpack .../nova-common_1%3a2014.1.3-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nova-common (1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nova-api.
Preparing to unpack .../nova-api_1%3a2014.1.3-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nova-api (1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nova-cert.
Preparing to unpack .../nova-cert_1%3a2014.1.3-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nova-cert (1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nova-conductor.
Preparing to unpack .../nova-conductor_1%3a2014.1.3-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nova-conductor (1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nova-consoleauth.
Preparing to unpack .../nova-consoleauth_1%3a2014.1.3-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nova-consoleauth (1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nova-novncproxy.
Preparing to unpack .../nova-novncproxy_1%3a2014.1.3-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nova-novncproxy (1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nova-scheduler.
Preparing to unpack .../nova-scheduler_1%3a2014.1.3-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nova-scheduler (1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up python-novaclient (1:2.17.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up nova-common (1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2) ...
usermod: no changes
2015-01-15 21:39:12.522 3931 INFO migrate.versioning.api [-] 215 -> 216... 
Command failed, please check log for more info
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 CRITICAL nova [-] OperationalError: (OperationalError) table instances already exists u"\nCREATE TABLE instances (\n\tcreated_at DATETIME, \n\tupdated_at DATETIME, \n\tdeleted_at DATETIME, \n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tinternal_id INTEGER, \n\tuser_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tproject_id VARCHAR(255), \n\timage_ref VARCHAR(255), \n\tkernel_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tramdisk_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tlaunch_index INTEGER, \n\tkey_name VARCHAR(255), \n\tkey_data TEXT, \n\tpower_state INTEGER, \n\tvm_state VARCHAR(255), \n\tmemory_mb INTEGER, \n\tvcpus INTEGER, \n\thostname VARCHAR(255), \n\thost VARCHAR(255), \n\tuser_data TEXT, \n\treservation_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tscheduled_at DATETIME, \n\tlaunched_at DATETIME, \n\tterminated_at DATETIME, \n\tdisplay_name VARCHAR(255), \n\tdisplay_description VARCHAR(255), \n\tavailability_zone VARCHAR(255), \n\tlocked BOOLEAN, \n\tos_type VARCHAR(255), \n\tlaunched_on TEXT, \n\tinstance_type_id INTEGER, \n\tvm_mode VARCHAR(255), \n\tuuid VARCHAR(36), \n\tarchitecture VARCHAR(255), \n\troot_device_name VARCHAR(255), \n\taccess_ip_v4 VARCHAR(39), \n\taccess_ip_v6 VARCHAR(39), \n\tconfig_drive VARCHAR(255), \n\ttask_state VARCHAR(255), \n\tdefault_ephemeral_device VARCHAR(255), \n\tdefault_swap_device VARCHAR(255), \n\tprogress INTEGER, \n\tauto_disk_config BOOLEAN, \n\tshutdown_terminate BOOLEAN, \n\tdisable_terminate BOOLEAN, \n\troot_gb INTEGER, \n\tephemeral_gb INTEGER, \n\tcell_name VARCHAR(255), \n\tnode VARCHAR(255), \n\tdeleted INTEGER, \n\tlocked_by VARCHAR(5), \n\tcleaned INTEGER, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id), \n\tCHECK (locked IN (0, 1)), \n\tCHECK (auto_disk_config IN (0, 1)), \n\tCHECK (shutdown_terminate IN (0, 1)), \n\tCHECK (disable_terminate IN (0, 1)), \n\tCONSTRAINT instances0locked_by CHECK (locked_by IN ('owner', 'admin'))\n)\n\n" ()
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/bin/nova-manage", line 10, in <module>
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     sys.exit(main())
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 1376, in main
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     ret = fn(*fn_args, **fn_kwargs)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 885, in sync
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     return migration.db_sync(version)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/migration.py", line 29, in db_sync
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     return IMPL.db_sync(version=version)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/sqlalchemy/migration.py", line 44, in db_sync
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     return versioning_api.upgrade(get_engine(), repository, version)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/migrate/versioning/api.py", line 186, in upgrade
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     return _migrate(url, repository, version, upgrade=True, err=err, **opts)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "<string>", line 2, in _migrate
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/migrate/versioning/util/__init__.py", line 159, in with_engine
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     return f(*a, **kw)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/migrate/versioning/api.py", line 366, in _migrate
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     schema.runchange(ver, change, changeset.step)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/migrate/versioning/schema.py", line 91, in runchange
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     change.run(self.engine, step)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/migrate/versioning/script/py.py", line 145, in run
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     script_func(engine)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/sqlalchemy/migrate_repo/versions/216_havana.py", line 1071, in upgrade
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     instances.create()
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 616, in create
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     checkfirst=checkfirst)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1479, in _run_visitor
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     conn._run_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1122, in _run_visitor
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 122, in traverse_single
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     return meth(obj, **kw)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/ddl.py", line 89, in visit_table
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     self.connection.execute(schema.CreateTable(table))
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 662, in execute
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     params)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 720, in _execute_ddl
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     compiled
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 874, in _execute_context
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     context)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1024, in _handle_dbapi_exception
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     exc_info
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 196, in raise_from_cause
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 867, in _execute_context
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     context)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 324, in do_execute
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova OperationalError: (OperationalError) table instances already exists u"\nCREATE TABLE instances (\n\tcreated_at DATETIME, \n\tupdated_at DATETIME, \n\tdeleted_at DATETIME, \n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tinternal_id INTEGER, \n\tuser_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tproject_id VARCHAR(255), \n\timage_ref VARCHAR(255), \n\tkernel_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tramdisk_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tlaunch_index INTEGER, \n\tkey_name VARCHAR(255), \n\tkey_data TEXT, \n\tpower_state INTEGER, \n\tvm_state VARCHAR(255), \n\tmemory_mb INTEGER, \n\tvcpus INTEGER, \n\thostname VARCHAR(255), \n\thost VARCHAR(255), \n\tuser_data TEXT, \n\treservation_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tscheduled_at DATETIME, \n\tlaunched_at DATETIME, \n\tterminated_at DATETIME, \n\tdisplay_name VARCHAR(255), \n\tdisplay_description VARCHAR(255), \n\tavailability_zone VARCHAR(255), \n\tlocked BOOLEAN, \n\tos_type VARCHAR(255), \n\tlaunched_on TEXT, \n\tinstance_type_id INTEGER, \n\tvm_mode VARCHAR(255), \n\tuuid VARCHAR(36), \n\tarchitecture VARCHAR(255), \n\troot_device_name VARCHAR(255), \n\taccess_ip_v4 VARCHAR(39), \n\taccess_ip_v6 VARCHAR(39), \n\tconfig_drive VARCHAR(255), \n\ttask_state VARCHAR(255), \n\tdefault_ephemeral_device VARCHAR(255), \n\tdefault_swap_device VARCHAR(255), \n\tprogress INTEGER, \n\tauto_disk_config BOOLEAN, \n\tshutdown_terminate BOOLEAN, \n\tdisable_terminate BOOLEAN, \n\troot_gb INTEGER, \n\tephemeral_gb INTEGER, \n\tcell_name VARCHAR(255), \n\tnode VARCHAR(255), \n\tdeleted INTEGER, \n\tlocked_by VARCHAR(5), \n\tcleaned INTEGER, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id), \n\tCHECK (locked IN (0, 1)), \n\tCHECK (auto_disk_config IN (0, 1)), \n\tCHECK (shutdown_terminate IN (0, 1)), \n\tCHECK (disable_terminate IN (0, 1)), \n\tCONSTRAINT instances0locked_by CHECK (locked_by IN ('owner', 'admin'))\n)\n\n" ()
2015-01-15 21:39:12.628 3931 TRACE nova 
dpkg: error processing package nova-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nova-api:
 nova-api depends on nova-common (= 1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package nova-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nova-api (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nova-cert:
 nova-cert depends on nova-common (= 1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package nova-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nova-cert (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nova-conductor:
 nova-conductor depends on nova-common (= 1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package nova-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nova-conductor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                              No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                  ent configuration of nova-consoleauth:
 nova-consoleauth depends on nova-common (= 1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package nova-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nova-consoleauth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nova-novncproxy:
 nova-novncproxy depends on nova-common (= 1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package nova-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nova-novncproxy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nova-scheduler:
 nova-scheduler depends on nova-common (= 1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package nova-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nova-scheduler (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nova-common
 nova-api
 nova-cert
 nova-conductor
 nova-consoleauth
 nova-novncproxy
 nova-scheduler
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Even if I try using:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I get this error:

```
controller@controller:~$ sudo apt-get -f install 
[sudo] password for controller: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Updating database of manual pages ...
Setting up nova-common (1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2) ...
usermod: no changes
2015-01-15 22:30:15.960 3601 INFO migrate.versioning.api [-] 215 -> 216... 
Command failed, please check log for more info
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 CRITICAL nova [-] OperationalError: (OperationalError) table instances already exists u"\nCREATE TABLE instances (\n\tcreated_at DATETIME, \n\tupdated_at DATETIME, \n\tdeleted_at DATETIME, \n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tinternal_id INTEGER, \n\tuser_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tproject_id VARCHAR(255), \n\timage_ref VARCHAR(255), \n\tkernel_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tramdisk_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tlaunch_index INTEGER, \n\tkey_name VARCHAR(255), \n\tkey_data TEXT, \n\tpower_state INTEGER, \n\tvm_state VARCHAR(255), \n\tmemory_mb INTEGER, \n\tvcpus INTEGER, \n\thostname VARCHAR(255), \n\thost VARCHAR(255), \n\tuser_data TEXT, \n\treservation_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tscheduled_at DATETIME, \n\tlaunched_at DATETIME, \n\tterminated_at DATETIME, \n\tdisplay_name VARCHAR(255), \n\tdisplay_description VARCHAR(255), \n\tavailability_zone VARCHAR(255), \n\tlocked BOOLEAN, \n\tos_type VARCHAR(255), \n\tlaunched_on TEXT, \n\tinstance_type_id INTEGER, \n\tvm_mode VARCHAR(255), \n\tuuid VARCHAR(36), \n\tarchitecture VARCHAR(255), \n\troot_device_name VARCHAR(255), \n\taccess_ip_v4 VARCHAR(39), \n\taccess_ip_v6 VARCHAR(39), \n\tconfig_drive VARCHAR(255), \n\ttask_state VARCHAR(255), \n\tdefault_ephemeral_device VARCHAR(255), \n\tdefault_swap_device VARCHAR(255), \n\tprogress INTEGER, \n\tauto_disk_config BOOLEAN, \n\tshutdown_terminate BOOLEAN, \n\tdisable_terminate BOOLEAN, \n\troot_gb INTEGER, \n\tephemeral_gb INTEGER, \n\tcell_name VARCHAR(255), \n\tnode VARCHAR(255), \n\tdeleted INTEGER, \n\tlocked_by VARCHAR(5), \n\tcleaned INTEGER, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id), \n\tCHECK (locked IN (0, 1)), \n\tCHECK (auto_disk_config IN (0, 1)), \n\tCHECK (shutdown_terminate IN (0, 1)), \n\tCHECK (disable_terminate IN (0, 1)), \n\tCONSTRAINT instances0locked_by CHECK (locked_by IN ('owner', 'admin'))\n)\n\n" ()
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/bin/nova-manage", line 10, in <module>
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     sys.exit(main())
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 1376, in main
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     ret = fn(*fn_args, **fn_kwargs)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 885, in sync
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     return migration.db_sync(version)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/migration.py", line 29, in db_sync
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     return IMPL.db_sync(version=version)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/sqlalchemy/migration.py", line 44, in db_sync
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     return versioning_api.upgrade(get_engine(), repository, version)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/migrate/versioning/api.py", line 186, in upgrade
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     return _migrate(url, repository, version, upgrade=True, err=err, **opts)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "<string>", line 2, in _migrate
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/migrate/versioning/util/__init__.py", line 159, in with_engine
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     return f(*a, **kw)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/migrate/versioning/api.py", line 366, in _migrate
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     schema.runchange(ver, change, changeset.step)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/migrate/versioning/schema.py", line 91, in runchange
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     change.run(self.engine, step)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/migrate/versioning/script/py.py", line 145, in run
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     script_func(engine)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/sqlalchemy/migrate_repo/versions/216_havana.py", line 1071, in upgrade
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     instances.create()
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 616, in create
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     checkfirst=checkfirst)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1479, in _run_visitor
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     conn._run_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1122, in _run_visitor
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 122, in traverse_single
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     return meth(obj, **kw)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/ddl.py", line 89, in visit_table
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     self.connection.execute(schema.CreateTable(table))
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 662, in execute
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     params)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 720, in _execute_ddl
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     compiled
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 874, in _execute_context
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     context)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1024, in _handle_dbapi_exception
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     exc_info
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 196, in raise_from_cause
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 867, in _execute_context
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     context)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 324, in do_execute
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova OperationalError: (OperationalError) table instances already exists u"\nCREATE TABLE instances (\n\tcreated_at DATETIME, \n\tupdated_at DATETIME, \n\tdeleted_at DATETIME, \n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tinternal_id INTEGER, \n\tuser_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tproject_id VARCHAR(255), \n\timage_ref VARCHAR(255), \n\tkernel_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tramdisk_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tlaunch_index INTEGER, \n\tkey_name VARCHAR(255), \n\tkey_data TEXT, \n\tpower_state INTEGER, \n\tvm_state VARCHAR(255), \n\tmemory_mb INTEGER, \n\tvcpus INTEGER, \n\thostname VARCHAR(255), \n\thost VARCHAR(255), \n\tuser_data TEXT, \n\treservation_id VARCHAR(255), \n\tscheduled_at DATETIME, \n\tlaunched_at DATETIME, \n\tterminated_at DATETIME, \n\tdisplay_name VARCHAR(255), \n\tdisplay_description VARCHAR(255), \n\tavailability_zone VARCHAR(255), \n\tlocked BOOLEAN, \n\tos_type VARCHAR(255), \n\tlaunched_on TEXT, \n\tinstance_type_id INTEGER, \n\tvm_mode VARCHAR(255), \n\tuuid VARCHAR(36), \n\tarchitecture VARCHAR(255), \n\troot_device_name VARCHAR(255), \n\taccess_ip_v4 VARCHAR(39), \n\taccess_ip_v6 VARCHAR(39), \n\tconfig_drive VARCHAR(255), \n\ttask_state VARCHAR(255), \n\tdefault_ephemeral_device VARCHAR(255), \n\tdefault_swap_device VARCHAR(255), \n\tprogress INTEGER, \n\tauto_disk_config BOOLEAN, \n\tshutdown_terminate BOOLEAN, \n\tdisable_terminate BOOLEAN, \n\troot_gb INTEGER, \n\tephemeral_gb INTEGER, \n\tcell_name VARCHAR(255), \n\tnode VARCHAR(255), \n\tdeleted INTEGER, \n\tlocked_by VARCHAR(5), \n\tcleaned INTEGER, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id), \n\tCHECK (locked IN (0, 1)), \n\tCHECK (auto_disk_config IN (0, 1)), \n\tCHECK (shutdown_terminate IN (0, 1)), \n\tCHECK (disable_terminate IN (0, 1)), \n\tCONSTRAINT instances0locked_by CHECK (locked_by IN ('owner', 'admin'))\n)\n\n" ()
2015-01-15 22:30:15.982 3601 TRACE nova 
dpkg: error processing package nova-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nova-api:
 nova-api depends on nova-common (= 1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package nova-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nova-api (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nova-cert:
 nova-cert depends on nova-common (= 1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package nova-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nova-cert (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nova-conductor:
 nova-conductor depends on nova-common (= 1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package nova-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nova-conductor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                        No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
          ent configuration of nova-consoleauth:
 nova-consoleauth depends on nova-common (= 1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package nova-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nova-consoleauth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nova-novncproxy:
 nova-novncproxy depends on nova-common (= 1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package nova-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nova-novncproxy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nova-scheduler:
 nova-scheduler depends on nova-common (= 1:2014.1.3-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package nova-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nova-scheduler (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nova-common
 nova-api
 nova-cert
 nova-conductor
 nova-consoleauth
 nova-novncproxy
 nova-scheduler
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this issue?

P.S: System and Ubuntu info:

```
controller@controller:~$ uname -a
Linux controller 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

controller@controller:~$ lsb_release  -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: The install script for SQL Alchemy is trying to configure a database for you, adding tables to hold data. However, those tables already exists in the database. So you can probably just drop the "instances" table, if you don't have anything important in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run:

```
sudo apt-get purge <package name>
```

For each of those packages and then try to install again. This will remove all packages and their configuration files etc, so you will be able to install them again without any problems.